# String that changes with cell value?

Tags: string, excel

I have a cell into which I've typed the text "The year is 2014."

However, in my case the year might change - it might be 2015 or 2017, etc. I'd like the text within this cell to change with the value of a referenced year cell.

So, if cell `A1=2015`, then I want `B1` to read "The year is 2015."

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `&`:

`="The year is "&A1&"."`

Or using function:

`=CONCATENATE("The year is ",A1,".")`

Answer (score 2):

Use following folrmula:

```
="The year is " & A1 & "."
```